# Extract the data in quarters using Pig

Tags: date, hadoop, apache-pig

I am new to Pig using -

Pig 0.12
Hadoop 1.2.1

I am working on a dataset as per the Programming Pig book and downloaded the data set NYSE daily. The table looks like this -

```
daily: {exchange: chararray,symbol: chararray,date: chararray,open: float,high: float,low: float,close: float,volume: float,adj_close: float}
```

Here is what I am trying to achieve -

1) Fetch all the data from the last quarter, process it and present a report with the performance of the share in that particular time period.

Here is what I did and now stuck -

```
daily = load 'NYSE_daily.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (exchange:chararray, symbol:chararray, date:chararray, open:float, high:float , low:float, close:float, volume:float, adj_close:float);
qtr_filter = FILTER daily by date >= '2009-10-01' and date <= '2009-12-31';
qtr_grp = group qtr_filter by date;
```

When I dump the records the result is like this -

```
2009-10-01  {(NYSE,APL,2009-10-01,7.27,7.28,6.96,7.01,532000.0,7.01),(NYSE,AVB,2009-10-01,72.38,72.45,68.46,68.49,2408800.0,67.78),(NYSE,AOB,2009-10-01,4.83,4.86,4.67,4.69,1705800.0,4.69),(NYSE,AXE,2009-10-01,40.0,40.0,38.75,38.98,304200.0,38.98),(NYSE,ACN,2009-10-01,37.04,37.5,36.39,36.53,6463200.0,35.83),(NYSE,ALG,2009-10-01,15.68,16.14,15.5,15.63,15500.0,15.52),(NYSE,ALX,2009-10-01,295.42,295.42,288.8,292.01,10000.0,292.01),(NYSE,AES,2009-10-01,14.77,14.83,13.83,13.83,8785300.0,13.83),(NYSE,AEH,2009-10-01,16.5,16.67,16.39,16.65,74500.0,16.28),(NYSE,ADS,2009-10-01,62.24,62.25,59.04,59.75,1068500.0,59.75),(NYSE,AKT,2009-10-01,7.32,7.6,7.23,7.4,25700.0,6.96),(NYSE,AMP,2009-10-01,35.79,37.72,35.79,36.97,8959200.0,36.79),(NYSE,ALC,2009-10-01,20.5,20.64,20.22,20.25,58400.0,20.25),(NYSE,ALEX,2009-10-01,32.0,32.53,31.45,31.52,183700.0,31.17),(NYSE,AMN,2009-10-01,69.34,70.22,66.32,68.0,143700.0,67.4),(NYSE,ATR,2009-10-01,37.11,37.13,36.39,36.42,209300.0,36.12),(NYSE,AGL,2009-10-01,35.28,35.28,34.47,34.74,326400.0,34.32),(NYSE,AKF,2009-10-01,7.41,7.59,7.3,7.44,19500.0,7.0),(NYSE,ALE,2009-10-01,33.44,33.73,33.23,33.23,149300.0,32.8),(NYSE,ASP,2009-10-01,11.21,11.21,11.17,11.17,1300.0,10.78),(NYSE,APF,2009-10-01,14.63,14.63,14.38,14.38,107300.0,14.12),(NYSE,ARW,2009-10-01,28.15,28.23,27.18,27.2,1081600.0,27.2),(NYSE,AZZ,2009-10-01,39.78,40.32,39.13,39.33,88500.0,39.01),(NYSE,AAV,2009-10-01,7.03,7.03,6.6,6.6,929800.0,6.6),(NYSE,ARP,2009-10-01,9.52,9.56,9.29,9.34,381100.0,9.34),(NYSE,AU,2009-10-01,40.39,40.43,38.61,38.73,4189100.0,38.73),(NYSE,AB,2009-10-01,27.16,27.72,25.76,25.84,507400.0,25.2),(NYSE,AKP,2009-10-01,13.35,13.43,13.35,13.42,20100.0,13.04),(NYSE,AIT,2009-10-01,21.15,21.17,20.24,20.27,289500.0,20.13),(NYSE,AXL,2009-10-01,7.08,7.15,6.59,6.71,3636900.0,6.71),(NYSE,ALY,2009-10-01,4.35,4.38,4.05,4.05,574700.0,4.05),(NYSE,AYN,2009-10-01,13.55,13.55,13.5,13.53,1400.0,13.19),(NYSE,ANW,2009-10-01,22.12,22.4,20.99,21.19,406100.0,21.18),(NYSE,AEL,2009-10-01,6.95,7.08,6.42,6.43,373900.0,6.36),(NYSE,AI,2009-10-01,0.49,0.49,0.47,0.48,39100.0,9.6),(NYSE,AWK,2009-10-01,19.99,19.99,19.68,19.77,617000.0,19.57),(NYSE,AMX,2009-10-01,43.2,43.98,42.19,42.38,4418300.0,42.38),(NYSE,ATV,2009-10-01,4.25,5.5,4.19,5.34,579700.0,5.34),(NYSE,AVX,2009-10-01,11.9,11.9,11.44,11.44,165700.0,11.4),(NYSE,AMR,2009-10-01,7.8,7.8,7.21,7.23,2.13386E7,7.23),(NYSE,AGN,2009-10-01,56.8,56.89,55.91,55.95,1398700.0,55.9),(NYSE,APC,2009-10-01,62.44,62.74,59.92,60.01,5462500.0,59.92),(NYSE,ABR,2009-10-01,2.8,2.89,2.57,2.89,292100.0,2.89),(NYSE,AM,2009-10-01,22.05,22.4,21.87,22.08,1268800.0,21.96),(NYSE,ALL,2009-10-01,30.7,31.41,30.38,30.4,7865900.0,30.19),(NYSE,ABM,2009-10-01,20.91,21.0,20.13,20.2,160700.0,19.94),(NYSE,ACM,2009-10-01,27.11,27.32,26.63,26.65,1176000.0,26.65),(NYSE,ACC,2009-10-01,26.77,26.79,25.68,26.11,990000.0,25.78),(NYSE,AF,2009-10-01,10.99,11.23,10.82,10.87,2040000.0,10.73),(NYSE,ALQ,2009-10-01,25.6,25.7,25.51,25.7,7500.0,24.98),(NYSE,ABT,2009-10-01,49.46,49.75,48.62,48.68,1.08364E7,47.94),(NYSE,ACO,2009-10-01,22.8,22.8,21.33,21.35,87000.0,21.22),(NYSE,ABK,2009-10-01,1.69,1.7,1.5,1.5,1.72808E7,1.5),(NYSE,AXA,2009-10-01,27.05,27.1,25.98,26.07,908600.0,26.07),(NYSE,ACH,2009-10-01,26.92,27.39,26.36,26.42,778900.0,26.42),(NYSE,AVD,2009-10-01,8.3,8.32,8.1,8.21,99700.0,8.21),(NYSE,AED,2009-10-01,16.73,16.74,16.43,16.66,53300.0,16.28),(NYSE,ACI,2009-10-01,21.95,22.08,20.91,20.98,5887900.0,20.89),(NYSE,ARD,2009-10-01,35.36,35.38,33.01,33.04,576500.0,33.04),(NYSE,ACS,2009-10-01,54.21,54.39,52.45,52.75,4667000.0,52.75),(NYSE,ALK,2009-10-01,26.75,26.75,25.44,25.47,473100.0,25.47),(NYSE,AFC,2009-10-01,13.08,13.23,13.08,13.11,14700.0,12.78),(NYSE,AWF,2009-10-01,12.65,12.65,12.52,12.55,226300.0,12.1),(NYSE,AVA,2009-10-01,20.1,20.4,20.07,20.21,282800.0,20.01),(NYSE,ADM,2009-10-01,29.05,29.21,28.68,28.86,5216800.0,28.73),(NYSE,AHL,2009-10-01,26.55,26.68,26.16,26.2,801100.0,26.05),(NYSE,AEV,2009-10-01,17.68,17.68,17.19,17.43,63800.0,17.02),(NYSE,AHS,2009-10-01,9.49,9.49,9.15,9.18,96600.0,9.18),(NYSE,AUO,2009-10-01,9.63,9.71,9.41,9.44,5082700.0,9.44),(NYSE,ACE,2009-10-01,53.36,54.48,53.36,53.75,3016000.0,53.42),(NYSE,AWC,2009-10-01,6.3,6.32,6.07,6.07,472000.0,6.07),(NYSE,ANN,2009-10-01,15.68,15.82,14.68,14.72,3289400.0,14.72),(NYSE,AFE,2009-10-01,22.06,22.5,22.06,22.5,3200.0,21.65),(NYSE,AEG,2009-10-01,8.42,8.43,8.01,8.03,592100.0,8.03),(NYSE,ATE,2009-10-01,26.17,26.26,25.6,25.68,34800.0,25.68),(NYSE,ABVT,2009-10-01,48.76,48.76,46.86,47.82,143200.0,47.82),(NYSE,ART,2009-10-01,26.25,26.38,25.34,25.35,722200.0,25.29),(NYSE,AEF,2009-10-01,18.46,18.48,18.2,18.4,162000.0,17.98),(NYSE,APH,2009-10-01,37.67,37.77,36.01,36.03,1450700.0,36.02),(NYSE,ABX,2009-10-01,38.1,38.1,36.08,36.18,1.26265E7,36.01),(NYSE,AWI,2009-10-01,33.83,34.68,33.83,34.17,711800.0,34.17),(NYSE,ACF,2009-10-01,15.79,15.84,15.0,15.02,1587100.0,15.02),(NYSE,ARM,2009-10-01,7.74,7.86,7.27,7.27,1797300.0,7.27),(NYSE,ASF,2009-10-01,26.2,26.34,25.01,25.11,150700.0,24.97),(NYSE,AYE,2009-10-01,26.41,26.48,25.61,25.63,2245600.0,25.46),(NYSE,APB,2009-10-01,9.51,9.56,9.41,9.44,34200.0,9.44),(NYSE,ATO,2009-10-01,28.18,28.5,27.71,27.78,404700.0,27.45),(NYSE,AEP,2009-10-01,31.24,31.24,30.75,30.85,4101900.0,30.08),(NYSE,AIN,2009-10-01,19.25,19.25,18.54,18.55,132100.0,18.45),(NYSE,APU,2009-10-01,36.69,36.69,35.0,35.05,120400.0,33.86),(NYSE,AVK,2009-10-01,14.8,14.8,14.58,14.6,77500.0,14.24),(NYSE,ARO,2009-10-01,43.16,43.25,41.23,42.02,3005600.0,42.02),(NYSE,AVP,2009-10-01,33.84,33.85,32.61,32.62,5395600.0,32.43),(NYSE,AMB,2009-10-01,22.66,22.74,21.18,21.22,4351100.0,20.99),(NYSE,AIZ,2009-10-01,31.9,32.14,30.9,30.94,762000.0,30.79),(NYSE,ASR,2009-10-01,42.73,43.64,41.58,41.78,84500.0,41.78),(NYSE,AAP,2009-10-01,39.25,39.25,37.79,37.94,2916800.0,37.89),(NYSE,ALV,2009-10-01,33.31,33.34,31.89,32.15,927000.0,32.15),(NYSE,AJG,2009-10-01,24.39,24.54,23.86,23.89,727600.0,23.55),(NYSE,AHC,2009-10-01,3.17,3.31,3.05,3.26,127100.0,3.26),(NYSE,ANH,2009-10-01,7.89,7.93,7.76,7.81,2468400.0,7.23),(NYSE,AMG,2009-10-01,64.71,64.71,62.0,62.0,546300.0,62.0),(NYSE,ADX,2009-10-01,9.75,9.75,9.53,9.54,152200.0,9.26),(NYSE,AVF,2009-10-01,14.3,14.34,13.75,13.95,208400.0,13.53),(NYSE,ALD,2009-10-01,3.05,3.06,2.89,2.9,1621100.0,2.9),(NYSE,ARK,2009-10-01,3.42,3.43,3.4,3.41,118500.0,3.31),(NYSE,AYR,2009-10-01,9.56,9.58,9.15,9.17,333700.0,9.07),(NYSE,AIR,2009-10-01,21.89,21.94,21.43,21.43,280000.0,21.43),(NYSE,ANF,2009-10-01,32.68,32.83,31.62,31.7,3680100.0,31.56),(NYSE,ASA,2009-10-01,75.16,75.6,73.81,74.34,85900.0,73.17),(NYSE,AIB,2009-10-01,9.59,9.62,8.84,8.93,1819900.0,8.93),(NYSE,AET,2009-10-01,27.77,28.38,27.54,27.58,6353700.0,27.54),(NYSE,ARE,2009-10-01,54.61,54.61,51.98,52.9,1984500.0,52.62),(NYSE,ABB,2009-10-01,19.85,19.89,19.44,19.46,2500900.0,19.46),(NYSE,AER,2009-10-01,8.96,9.08,8.51,8.54,513500.0,8.54),(NYSE,AP,2009-10-01,26.5,27.02,26.34,26.52,21400.0,26.21),(NYSE,AOS,2009-10-01,38.09,38.17,36.98,37.03,134100.0,36.69),(NYSE,AIG,2009-10-01,43.57,43.68,40.15,40.9,2.68266E7,40.9),(NYSE,AHD,2009-10-01,3.75,3.79,3.5,3.5,192100.0,3.5),(NYSE,AWR,2009-10-01,36.12,36.23,35.54,35.56,43500.0,35.29),(NYSE,AOD,2009-10-01,8.95,8.96,8.6,8.76,994300.0,8.31),(NYSE,AWH,2009-10-01,48.21,48.99,47.16,47.19,234600.0,46.99),(NYSE,AMT,2009-10-01,35.55,35.95,35.23,35.38,5025100.0,35.38),(NYSE,ATK,2009-10-01,77.76,78.69,76.57,76.64,407400.0,76.64),(NYSE,AEE,2009-10-01,25.28,25.37,24.75,24.8,2502000.0,24.45),(NYSE,ABG,2009-10-01,12.47,12.54,12.15,12.31,283300.0,12.31),(NYSE,AYI,2009-10-01,32.13,32.3,31.12,31.16,438600.0,30.94),(NYSE,ALZ,2009-10-01,25.34,25.39,25.24,25.28,8400.0,24.91),(NYSE,AME,2009-10-01,34.87,34.87,33.88,34.33,534700.0,34.27),(NYSE,ABV,2009-10-01,84.09,84.35,81.59,83.26,1063300.0,82.18),(NYSE,ASI,2009-10-01,15.98,16.0,14.88,14.88,21500.0,14.88),(NYSE,AUY,2009-10-01,10.8,10.8,10.05,10.12,1.79389E7,10.11),(NYSE,ACL,2009-10-01,138.85,139.63,136.25,137.28,501500.0,137.28),(NYSE,AFF,2009-10-01,11.82,12.14,11.77,12.02,90700.0,11.65),(NYSE,AAI,2009-10-01,6.24,6.24,5.75,5.78,2156400.0,5.78),(NYSE,AA,2009-10-01,13.36,13.62,12.9,12.92,5.17794E7,12.86),(NYSE,ANR,2009-10-01,34.84,35.03,33.67,33.8,2619200.0,33.8),(NYSE,ADI,2009-10-01,27.57,27.7,26.57,26.57,5957300.0,26.4),(NYSE,ADP,2009-10-01,39.17,39.4,38.73,38.95,3938300.0,38.64),(NYSE,ALF,2009-10-01,25.02,25.1,25.0,25.0,7800.0,24.65),(NYSE,ASH,2009-10-01,42.8,42.85,40.01,40.19,1623900.0,40.11),(NYSE,ATW,2009-10-01,35.02,35.3,33.64,33.64,1125400.0,33.64),(NYSE,AEA,2009-10-01,5.56,5.67,5.36,5.5,351800.0,5.44),(NYSE,AAN,2009-10-01,26.11,26.82,25.81,26.6,908900.0,26.58),(NYSE,ABC,2009-10-01,22.36,22.49,21.85,22.03,3969500.0,21.96),(NYSE,AXP,2009-10-01,33.85,33.89,32.42,32.46,1.51684E7,32.32),(NYSE,ATT,2009-10-01,26.76,26.79,26.5,26.59,109900.0,25.8),(NYSE,ATU,2009-10-01,16.02,16.13,15.6,15.99,1102100.0,15.99),(NYSE,AVY,2009-10-01,35.92,35.99,34.58,34.73,1641600.0,34.55),(NYSE,ACV,2009-10-01,27.76,27.79,27.22,27.25,479800.0,27.17),(NYSE,ALM,2009-10-01,26.14,26.24,26.01,26.12,11900.0,25.75),(NYSE,ARI,2009-10-01,18.2,18.29,18.12,18.15,726800.0,18.15),(NYSE,AEM,2009-10-01,68.0,68.03,63.96,64.19,4531400.0,64.19),(NYSE,AGO,2009-10-01,19.43,19.47,18.21,18.23,1140000.0,18.2),(NYSE,AN,2009-10-01,17.83,18.06,17.25,17.4,3297600.0,17.4),(NYSE,ARJ,2009-10-01,29.75,30.17,29.22,29.52,128500.0,29.31),(NYSE,APD,2009-10-01,77.67,77.8,75.4,75.4,1814200.0,74.99),(NYSE,ARG,2009-10-01,48.39,48.39,46.53,46.86,1203300.0,46.68),(NYSE,AKR,2009-10-01,14.99,15.05,14.09,14.17,564000.0,14.02),(NYSE,AIQ,2009-10-01,5.62,5.67,5.5,5.56,229600.0,5.56),(NYSE,AGU,2009-10-01,49.79,49.91,47.57,47.68,2013600.0,47.64),(NYSE,AFN,2009-10-01,1.19,1.25,1.05,1.11,1183400.0,1.11),(NYSE,AIV,2009-10-01,14.67,14.7,13.92,13.95,4725200.0,13.77),(NYSE,AKS,2009-10-01,19.63,19.92,18.31,18.34,1.07827E7,18.29),(NYSE,AGM,2009-10-01,7.44,7.45,7.09,7.11,190500.0,7.05),(NYSE,AEB,2009-10-01,14.51,14.8,14.35,14.38,40700.0,14.14),(NYSE,APA,2009-10-01,91.49,92.03,89.35,89.6,4646400.0,89.35),(NYSE,ALU,2009-10-01,4.39,4.4,4.17,4.2,1.11352E7,4.2),(NYSE,ABD,2009-10-01,7.2,7.28,6.88,6.89,453400.0,6.89),(NYSE,AZN,2009-10-01,44.8,44.81,43.94,43.96,1708000.0,42.36),(NYSE,ABA,2009-10-01,26.26,26.27,26.15,26.27,13700.0,25.88),(NYSE,AMD,2009-10-01,5.62,5.65,5.27,5.39,4.27595E7,5.39),(NYSE,AHT,2009-10-01,3.45,3.53,3.32,3.32,1049100.0,3.32),(NYSE,APX,2009-10-01,8.66,8.66,8.59,8.66,20800.0,8.46),(NYSE,AVT,2009-10-01,25.97,26.0,25.08,25.12,1280700.0,25.12),(NYSE,ASG,2009-10-01,3.13,3.13,3.09,3.09,91300.0,3.03),(NYSE,ACG,2009-10-01,8.29,8.3,8.26,8.27,355900.0,8.03),(NYSE,ALB,2009-10-01,34.41,34.44,32.53,32.56,870100.0,32.45),(NYSE,AGC,2009-10-01,7.69,7.83,7.69,7.77,187600.0,7.52),(NYSE,AON,2009-10-01,40.82,41.45,40.58,40.74,2827200.0,40.43),(NYSE,AFB,2009-10-01,13.75,13.85,13.7,13.7,62400.0,13.32),(NYSE,AEC,2009-10-01,9.53,10.1,9.51,9.67,120800.0,9.36),(NYSE,AXR,2009-10-01,13.33,13.37,12.77,13.06,15500.0,13.06),(NYSE,AEO,2009-10-01,16.69,16.74,16.01,16.14,8349200.0,15.95),(NYSE,ATI,2009-10-01,34.93,34.93,33.2,33.28,3021700.0,33.12),(NYSE,ARL,2009-10-01,11.48,11.48,11.3,11.3,2000.0,11.3),(NYSE,AWP,2009-10-01,6.3,6.3,6.0,6.1,452400.0,5.98),(NYSE,AOI,2009-10-01,4.45,4.49,4.37,4.41,520700.0,4.41),(NYSE,AGD,2009-10-01,9.58,9.58,9.1,9.11,114200.0,8.72),(NYSE,AAR,2009-10-01,18.19,18.3,18.01,18.1,15700.0,17.22),(NYSE,ARB,2009-10-01,20.49,21.79,20.33,20.87,813700.0,20.77),(NYSE,AZO,2009-10-01,145.77,147.06,144.13,145.62,1380100.0,145.62),(NYSE,ALJ,2009-10-01,9.84,9.88,9.52,9.53,99400.0,9.48),(NYSE,ADY,2009-10-01,28.22,28.22,27.0,27.08,159000.0,27.08),(NYSE,AGP,2009-10-01,22.13,22.4,21.93,22.1,615200.0,22.1),(NYSE,AGCO,2009-10-01,27.38,27.59,26.06,26.15,2082600.0,26.15),(NYSE,AFG,2009-10-01,25.41,25.48,24.81,24.86,642400.0,24.6),(NYSE,ADC,2009-10-01,22.73,22.73,21.38,21.48,75200.0,21.04),(NYSE,ASX,2009-10-01,3.98,4.12,3.95,4.01,848600.0,4.01),(NYSE,AFL,2009-10-01,42.44,42.75,40.55,40.71,5442900.0,40.45),(NYSE,AXS,2009-10-01,30.11,30.4,29.63,29.69,1356200.0,29.47)}
2009-10-02  {(NYSE,AAV,2009-10-02,6.42,6.42,6.12,6.35,1151100.0,6.35),(NYSE,AEP,2009-10-02,30.72,30.78,30.33,30.37,3248600.0,29.61),(NYSE,AAN,2009-10-02,26.28,26.81,26.25,26.36,345100.0,26.34),(NYSE,ATO,2009-10-02,27.7,27.93,27.45,27.68,557100.0,27.35),(NYSE,ATW,2009-10-02,33.0,33.18,32.06,32.69,992100.0,32.69),(NYSE,ALK,2009-10-02,25.2,26.25,25.2,25.81,386700.0,25.81),(NYSE,AGC,2009-10-02,7.69,7.77,7.61,7.7,157700.0,7.45),(NYSE,AME,2009-10-02,34.16,34.34,33.29,33.33,592200.0,33.28),(NYSE,ACS,2009-10-02,51.96,52.42,51.5,52.0,3755700.0,52.0),(NYSE,ALJ,2009-10-02,9.26,9.78,9.25,9.59,80500.0,9.54),(NYSE,AYE,2009-10-02,25.36,25.6,25.07,25.4,1774300.0,25.23),(NYSE,APB,2009-10-02,9.33,9.37,9.11,9.35,28600.0,9.35),(NYSE,ASF,2009-10-02,24.91,25.28,24.73,24.91,93900.0,24.77),(NYSE,AKF,2009-10-02,7.4,7.4,7.3,7.35,6800.0,6.92),(NYSE,APH,2009-10-02,35.75,35.91,35.16,35.47,1214600.0,35.46),(NYSE,ARD,2009-10-02,32.42,33.25,32.25,32.76,511300.0,32.76),(NYSE,ALF,2009-10-02,25.01,25.08,25.0,25.0,5900.0,24.65),(NYSE,ARM,2009-10-02,7.22,7.24,6.84,6.85,2772800.0,6.85),(NYSE,ARL,2009-10-02,11.18,11.2,11.05,11.05,2000.0,11.05),(NYSE,ALB,2009-10-02,32.05,32.37,31.6,31.76,999200.0,31.65),(NYSE,ACF,2009-10-02,14.75,15.35,14.71,14.97,1222400.0,14.97),(NYSE,AWI,2009-10-02,34.39,34.39,33.32,33.4,480000.0,33.4),(NYSE,AVX,2009-10-02,11.42,11.48,11.22,11.24,110000.0,11.2),(NYSE,ALZ,2009-10-02,25.28,25.34,25.21,25.29,5800.0,24.92),(NYSE,AFC,2009-10-02,13.08,13.25,12.95,13.12,12500.0,12.79),(NYSE,AGO,2009-10-02,17.88,18.48,17.84,18.15,1891300.0,18.12),(NYSE,ABX,2009-10-02,35.9,36.9,35.71,36.1,1.54785E7,35.93),(NYSE,AEF,2009-10-02,18.25,18.25,17.73,18.1,104100.0,17.68),(NYSE,ALY,2009-10-02,4.0,4.3,3.85,4.15,748700.0,4.15),(NYSE,ACN,2009-10-02,37.11,38.24,36.9,37.5,1.13156E7,36.79),(NYSE,ALE,2009-10-02,33.07,33.33,32.75,32.96,156400.0,32.53),(NYSE,ART,2009-10-02,24.77,25.38,24.05,25.29,1172800.0,25.23),(NYSE,ABVT,2009-10-02,47.35,48.41,47.35,47.67,53100.0,47.67),(NYSE,ACM,2009-10-02,26.52,26.89,26.25,26.33,784200.0,26.33),(NYSE,AWF,2009-10-02,12.51,12.52,12.28,12.4,306400.0,11.95),(NYSE,ABG,2009-10-02,12.18,12.45,11.91,12.29,233800.0,12.29),(NYSE,AZZ,2009-10-02,38.72,39.33,38.44,38.54,71100.0,38.23),(NYSE,AWK,2009-10-02,19.73,19.73,19.11,19.53,1489600.0,19.33),(NYSE,ADM,2009-10-02,28.72,28.78,27.66,28.43,3855200.0,28.31),(NYSE,ATE,2009-10-02,25.32,25.41,25.11,25.25,11000.0,25.25),(NYSE,ATI,2009-10-02,32.5,34.04,31.8,33.67,2625300.0,33.51),(NYSE,ANW,2009-10-02,20.91,21.27,20.74,20.95,250900.0,20.94),(NYSE,ASP,2009-10-02,11.06,11.18,11.06,11.18,600.0,10.79),(NYSE,ABT,2009-10-02,48.41,50.0,48.41,49.84,1.28174E7,49.08),(NYSE,AVA,2009-10-02,20.06,20.21,19.79,20.05,286200.0,19.85),(NYSE,ATV,2009-10-02,5.33,5.33,4.8,5.33,124300.0,5.33),(NYSE,AEG,2009-10-02,7.58,8.1,7.53,7.85,708400.0,7.85),(NYSE,AEO,2009-10-02,16.04,16.33,15.91,16.07,4927900.0,15.88),(NYSE,AFE,2009-10-02,22.5,23.45,22.21,23.42,9600.0,22.54),(NYSE,ANN,2009-10-02,14.42,14.86,14.02,14.61,2619900.0,14.61),(NYSE,AMD,2009-10-02,5.22,5.45,5.05,5.31,3.18218E7,5.31),(NYSE,AHL,2009-10-02,26.23,27.17,26.07,26.98,853100.0,26.83),(NYSE,ASH,2009-10-02,39.45,39.45,37.94,38.22,2263600.0,38.14),(NYSE,AWC,2009-10-02,5.82,6.05,5.8,5.98,279600.0,5.98),(NYSE,APF,2009-10-02,14.2,14.3,14.15,14.26,38300.0,14.0),(NYSE,ACE,2009-10-02,53.24,54.0,52.92,53.76,1822100.0,53.43),(NYSE,AMX,2009-10-02,41.7,42.92,41.46,42.63,5094000.0,42.63),(NYSE,AEV,2009-10-02,17.07,17.18,16.52,17.09,80900.0,16.69),(NYSE,AN,2009-10-02,17.16,17.41,16.68,17.25,3844600.0,17.25),(NYSE,ARW,2009-10-02,27.0,27.21,26.72,26.86,736900.0,26.86),(NYSE,AIT,2009-10-02,20.0,20.14,19.65,19.68,220300.0,19.54),(NYSE,AEE,2009-10-02,24.73,24.74,24.27,24.52,2098800.0,24.17),(NYSE,ATU,2009-10-02,15.78,15.87,15.05,15.12,988600.0,15.12),(NYSE,AUO,2009-10-02,9.37,9.5,9.32,9.45,6802000.0,9.45),(NYSE,AHS,2009-10-02,9.84,9.89,9.48,9.6,366300.0,9.6),(NYSE,AGCO,2009-10-02,26.06,26.84,25.77,26.54,1972300.0,26.54),(NYSE,ABC,2009-10-02,21.9,21.92,21.57,21.62,2450900.0,21.55),(NYSE,ATK,2009-10-02,76.21,76.8,75.45,75.77,441000.0,75.77),(NYSE,AES,2009-10-02,13.69,13.94,13.41,13.78,6396300.0,13.78),(NYSE,ATT,2009-10-02,26.5,26.72,26.4,26.41,135900.0,25.62),(NYSE,ARJ,2009-10-02,29.08,29.8,28.86,29.62,87900.0,29.41),(NYSE,AM,2009-10-02,21.77,21.92,21.11,21.49,1183400.0,21.37),(NYSE,AMT,2009-10-02,35.09,36.13,35.03,35.65,3937900.0,35.65),(NYSE,APD,2009-10-02,74.7,76.33,73.76,75.53,1767000.0,75.12),(NYSE,AEA,2009-10-02,5.4,5.55,5.3,5.51,279200.0,5.45),(NYSE,ASG,2009-10-02,3.08,3.1,3.05,3.07,38300.0,3.01),(NYSE,APX,2009-10-02,8.67,8.69,8.63,8.68,26100.0,8.48),(NYSE,AWH,2009-10-02,47.02,47.02,46.22,46.8,457300.0,46.6),(NYSE,AB,2009-10-02,25.45,25.89,24.4,24.52,829400.0,23.91),(NYSE,AOD,2009-10-02,8.7,8.7,8.17,8.41,1924600.0,7.98),(NYSE,ALM,2009-10-02,26.12,26.19,25.25,26.1,28600.0,25.73),(NYSE,ARG,2009-10-02,46.25,47.89,46.04,47.3,1072900.0,47.12),(NYSE,AFG,2009-10-02,24.6,25.03,24.45,24.69,500900.0,24.43),(NYSE,AFL,2009-10-02,40.08,41.52,39.82,41.1,4043500.0,40.84),(NYSE,AEH,2009-10-02,16.45,16.53,15.97,16.51,78700.0,16.14),(NYSE,AEL,2009-10-02,6.31,6.51,6.1,6.46,346200.0,6.39),(NYSE,AOB,2009-10-02,4.62,4.73,4.6,4.71,758700.0,4.71),(NYSE,AVY,2009-10-02,32.87,34.09,32.87,33.95,2066900.0,33.77),(NYSE,AKR,2009-10-02,13.85,14.48,13.47,14.14,323900.0,13.99),(NYSE,AXP,2009-10-02,31.95,33.23,31.69,32.49,1.22155E7,32.35),(NYSE,AWR,2009-10-02,35.37,35.7,35.13,35.32,45900.0,35.06),(NYSE,AHD,2009-10-02,3.38,3.44,3.35,3.41,101100.0,3.41),(NYSE,AU,2009-10-02,38.21,39.99,38.05,38.8,3646300.0,38.8),(NYSE,ABM,2009-10-02,20.06,20.34,20.06,20.18,87400.0,19.92),(NYSE,AIG,2009-10-02,39.05,43.33,36.86,43.08,4.70581E7,43.08),(NYSE,AFB,2009-10-02,13.78,13.85,13.75,13.85,34900.0,13.47),(NYSE,AOS,2009-10-02,36.78,37.62,36.67,36.94,195600.0,36.6),(NYSE,AYI,2009-10-02,30.77,31.29,30.56,30.98,227100.0,30.76),(NYSE,ADS,2009-10-02,58.56,59.75,58.56,58.9,873000.0,58.9),(NYSE,ADI,2009-10-02,26.43,26.87,26.22,26.26,4945400.0,26.09),(NYSE,AIQ,2009-10-02,5.5,5.78,5.45,5.71,323000.0,5.71),(NYSE,AER,2009-10-02,8.41,8.56,7.97,8.29,798600.0,8.29),(NYSE,ABA,2009-10-02,26.09,26.26,26.08,26.2,5500.0,25.81),(NYSE,AZO,2009-10-02,144.21,147.32,143.82,146.05,1132100.0,146.05),(NYSE,AGU,2009-10-02,46.82,47.48,45.98,46.88,1603500.0,46.84),(NYSE,ADP,2009-10-02,38.89,39.35,38.55,38.79,4463900.0,38.48),(NYSE,ALL,2009-10-02,29.97,31.25,29.79,30.76,5149400.0,30.55),(NYSE,ABB,2009-10-02,19.13,19.48,19.12,19.42,3371100.0,19.42),(NYSE,ARE,2009-10-02,52.16,53.48,51.35,51.8,1145300.0,51.53),(NYSE,AP,2009-10-02,26.5,27.18,26.42,26.51,33300.0,26.2),(NYSE,ALQ,2009-10-02,25.79,26.88,25.67,26.88,10800.0,26.13),(NYSE,ACO,2009-10-02,21.0,21.19,20.69,20.94,95100.0,20.81),(NYSE,AXR,2009-10-02,12.88,13.12,12.75,13.0,4100.0,13.0),(NYSE,AET,2009-10-02,27.33,27.5,26.5,26.73,6237500.0,26.69),(NYSE,AF,2009-10-02,10.71,10.93,10.34,10.8,852300.0,10.66),(NYSE,AFN,2009-10-02,1.06,1.11,1.0,1.07,993300.0,1.07),(NYSE,ARB,2009-10-02,20.73,21.26,20.5,21.22,317500.0,21.12),(NYSE,AIB,2009-10-02,8.28,8.8,8.09,8.6,2198900.0,8.6),(NYSE,AKT,2009-10-02,7.32,7.44,7.21,7.26,9900.0,6.83),(NYSE,AXL,2009-10-02,6.35,6.62,6.05,6.34,4804200.0,6.34),(NYSE,AIV,2009-10-02,13.7,14.52,13.5,14.09,3908300.0,13.9),(NYSE,ADY,2009-10-02,27.25,27.99,26.35,27.65,166000.0,27.65),(NYSE,AIR,2009-10-02,21.31,22.1,21.15,21.95,729700.0,21.95),(NYSE,ASA,2009-10-02,72.56,74.55,72.25,73.25,65400.0,72.1),(NYSE,ABK,2009-10-02,1.45,1.57,1.41,1.51,1.68154E7,1.51),(NYSE,AA,2009-10-02,12.6,13.1,12.51,12.82,3.44803E7,12.76),(NYSE,ABD,2009-10-02,6.67,6.86,6.26,6.48,402100.0,6.48),(NYSE,ANF,2009-10-02,31.1,31.65,30.52,30.62,4255500.0,30.48),(NYSE,ABR,2009-10-02,2.73,2.8,2.61,2.76,226800.0,2.76),(NYSE,AEC,2009-10-02,9.53,9.6,9.15,9.44,80100.0,9.14),(NYSE,ANR,2009-10-02,33.03,34.38,32.62,33.98,3532500.0,33.98),(NYSE,AKS,2009-10-02,17.88,18.51,17.57,18.05,1.22142E7,18.0),(NYSE,ADC,2009-10-02,21.12,21.63,20.99,21.01,53800.0,20.58),(NYSE,AAI,2009-10-02,5.65,6.24,5.65,6.05,3113400.0,6.05),(NYSE,AGM,2009-10-02,7.06,7.22,6.71,7.03,168800.0,6.97),(NYSE,ASX,2009-10-02,3.87,3.99,3.8,3.91,2124300.0,3.91),(NYSE,AMP,2009-10-02,36.23,37.8,36.12,36.43,5499100.0,36.25),(NYSE,AYR,2009-10-02,9.14,9.3,8.79,9.05,239500.0,8.96),(NYSE,AFF,2009-10-02,11.78,12.09,11.45,11.9,109400.0,11.54),(NYSE,AVB,2009-10-02,67.71,70.38,67.13,67.99,1544700.0,67.29),(NYSE,ACL,2009-10-02,136.0,137.71,135.67,136.28,465900.0,136.28),(NYSE,ARK,2009-10-02,3.37,3.4,3.29,3.39,193300.0,3.29),(NYSE,AGD,2009-10-02,8.78,9.18,8.5,8.83,247600.0,8.45),(NYSE,AWP,2009-10-02,6.0,6.0,5.81,5.94,542800.0,5.83),(NYSE,ACC,2009-10-02,25.74,27.03,25.62,25.99,1093900.0,25.67),(NYSE,AEB,2009-10-02,14.3,14.3,13.88,14.14,68200.0,13.9),(NYSE,ALD,2009-10-02,2.87,2.98,2.75,2.84,1761200.0,2.84),(NYSE,AVF,2009-10-02,13.72,14.24,13.36,14.07,216400.0,13.65),(NYSE,APC,2009-10-02,58.99,60.06,58.17,59.73,5469800.0,59.64),(NYSE,AON,2009-10-02,40.43,40.74,40.29,40.35,2464200.0,40.05),(NYSE,ADX,2009-10-02,9.41,9.55,9.41,9.47,151800.0,9.19),(NYSE,ALC,2009-10-02,19.94,20.26,19.75,19.94,25200.0,19.94),(NYSE,AMG,2009-10-02,61.57,63.08,61.0,61.27,334300.0,61.27),(NYSE,APA,2009-10-02,88.51,90.9,88.06,89.95,3884400.0,89.7),(NYSE,AXE,2009-10-02,38.77,38.89,38.22,38.5,296800.0,38.5),(NYSE,AHC,2009-10-02,3.17,3.29,3.05,3.28,140200.0,3.28),(NYSE,AKP,2009-10-02,13.45,13.45,13.4,13.45,6000.0,13.07),(NYSE,AXA,2009-10-02,25.76,26.37,25.65,26.23,591600.0,26.23),(NYSE,ALU,2009-10-02,4.08,4.32,4.07,4.19,1.55884E7,4.19),(NYSE,AZN,2009-10-02,43.49,44.05,43.46,43.64,1660700.0,42.05),(NYSE,ARI,2009-10-02,18.23,18.41,18.15,18.3,238900.0,18.3),(NYSE,AGP,2009-10-02,21.87,22.24,21.78,22.0,727100.0,22.0),(NYSE,AJG,2009-10-02,23.74,23.88,23.62,23.72,687800.0,23.39),(NYSE,AAR,2009-10-02,18.01,18.16,17.96,18.03,11100.0,17.16),(NYSE,ALX,2009-10-02,290.07,295.98,290.0,290.58,8600.0,290.58),(NYSE,AUY,2009-10-02,10.04,10.48,9.98,10.05,1.68956E7,10.04),(NYSE,ALV,2009-10-02,31.72,32.0,31.03,31.08,1059100.0,31.08),(NYSE,APL,2009-10-02,6.9,7.11,6.66,6.98,670300.0,6.98),(NYSE,AI,2009-10-02,0.46,0.47,0.44,0.45,74400.0,9.0),(NYSE,AAP,2009-10-02,37.67,38.2,37.4,37.48,2629300.0,37.43),(NYSE,ANH,2009-10-02,7.75,7.97,7.75,7.92,2162800.0,7.34),(NYSE,ASI,2009-10-02,14.72,15.1,14.52,14.64,14800.0,14.64),(NYSE,ALEX,2009-10-02,31.15,31.64,30.33,30.39,220700.0,30.05),(NYSE,ASR,2009-10-02,41.35,42.17,41.27,41.9,35300.0,41.9),(NYSE,ALG,2009-10-02,15.47,15.96,15.47,15.51,25700.0,15.4),(NYSE,ACG,2009-10-02,8.27,8.3,8.27,8.29,359700.0,8.05),(NYSE,ACV,2009-10-02,27.13,27.77,27.11,27.48,549000.0,27.4),(NYSE,AIZ,2009-10-02,30.46,31.32,30.05,30.85,1078900.0,30.7),(NYSE,AMB,2009-10-02,20.86,22.08,20.71,21.21,3832900.0,20.98),(NYSE,AGN,2009-10-02,55.4,55.79,54.25,54.96,2549600.0,54.91),(NYSE,AHT,2009-10-02,3.26,3.38,3.08,3.27,810400.0,3.27),(NYSE,ACH,2009-10-02,25.91,26.38,25.73,26.14,722900.0,26.14),(NYSE,ARP,2009-10-02,9.25,9.49,9.25,9.36,258100.0,9.36),(NYSE,AVP,2009-10-02,32.49,32.94,32.01,32.61,4477800.0,32.42),(NYSE,AVD,2009-10-02,8.15,8.45,8.11,8.35,88900.0,8.35),(NYSE,AMN,2009-10-02,67.2,70.0,66.52,67.81,108000.0,67.21),(NYSE,ARO,2009-10-02,41.27,42.3,41.07,41.83,1399600.0,41.83),(NYSE,AYN,2009-10-02,13.54,13.64,13.53,13.64,5200.0,13.29),(NYSE,ATR,2009-10-02,36.05,36.46,36.03,36.12,115700.0,35.82),(NYSE,AVK,2009-10-02,14.4,14.45,14.33,14.38,56400.0,14.03),(NYSE,AEM,2009-10-02,63.55,66.44,63.2,63.87,4638900.0,63.87),(NYSE,ACI,2009-10-02,20.36,21.22,20.07,20.49,6741800.0,20.41),(NYSE,AXS,2009-10-02,29.41,30.17,29.25,29.99,1053600.0,29.77),(NYSE,AED,2009-10-02,16.48,16.6,16.03,16.6,58400.0,16.22),(NYSE,ABV,2009-10-02,81.53,84.41,81.28,84.16,1034700.0,83.07),(NYSE,AMR,2009-10-02,6.98,7.5,6.9,7.46,2.22154E7,7.46),(NYSE,APU,2009-10-02,35.05,35.16,34.62,34.79,118400.0,33.61),(NYSE,AOI,2009-10-02,4.35,4.56,4.32,4.52,691500.0,4.52),(NYSE,AGL,2009-10-02,34.59,34.92,34.11,34.84,368600.0,34.42),(NYSE,AVT,2009-10-02,24.8,25.03,24.49,24.53,910300.0,24.53),(NYSE,AIN,2009-10-02,18.55,18.85,17.49,18.33,207800.0,18.23)}
```

However the desired output required is for 1 quarter only which I am unable to do.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I am a little unclear on what the problem is here.  Do you want each row of your output to be for one stock only representing that stock for the quarter that you want? Do you want each row only to be the single stock, or do you also want one row per stock per quarter?

Comment: What I need to do is get all the data for a quarter including everything that is stock, exchange, price etc.

Comment: That is not helpful. Do you want one row of output per quarter.  Do you want one row of output with just one quarter and all the data.  Do you want one row per stock that contains all the data for all days in the quarter.  Please be as specific as possible then I can help you.

Comment: Sorry for being not so specific - One row of output with just one quarter and all the data for that quarter. Please see the desired output which is required - NYSE,AEA,2010-01-08,4.42,4.42,4.21,4.24,205500,4.24
NYSE,AEA,2010-02-05,4.42,4.54,4.22,4.41,194300,4.41
NYSE,AEA,2010-03-04,4.55,4.69,4.39,4.42,233800,4.42 - This data is for once quarter which I need. Hope this helps.

Comment: Correction - Sorry for being not so specific - One row per stock that contains all the data for all days in the specific quarter. Please see the desired output which is required - NYSE,AEA,2010-01-08,4.42,4.42,4.21,4.24,205500,4.24
NYSE,AEA,2010-02-05,4.42,4.54,4.22,4.41,194300,4.41
NYSE,AEA,2010-03-04,4.55,4.69,4.39,4.42,233800,4.42 - This data is for once quarter which I need. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is this:

```
daily = load 'NYSE_daily.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (exchange:chararray, symbol:chararray, date:chararray, open:float, high:float , low:float, close:float, volume:float, adj_close:float);
qtr_filter = FILTER daily by date >= '2009-10-01' and date <= '2009-12-31';
grouped_by_stock = group qtr_filter by symbol;
```

each line of your output will be for 1 stock symbol and will contain all the daily data for that symbol.  It will not be ordered though so if you want to use that data in order must order it first.

Comment: Thanks I think I got it now thanks for all your help

Comment: I was thinking that while executing the script can I pass the parameters I have been trying to incorporate 2 variables to accept the start and end date of the quarter however, unable to do that. Any thoughts.

Comment: you appear to be asking another question.  If so ask another question, the comments is not the place to do it